# Asymmetrical basketball

Tags: modeling

I am creating a basketball based on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjdv-Q-qCNU) tutorial. Now , just before UV unwrapping this is my basketball:

[image]

At this point in the tutorial (about 12:30 min) this text is presented:

> A viewer pointed out that the valleys on a real basketball are not
>   symmetrical on the sides like my model. If you care about that, then
>   before proceeding here select the right half of the basketball in side
>   view, press Y to split it, then rotate it 90 degrees in front view and
>   remove doubles. Do this for the rubber too and fix any seams. Look at
>   a real basketball to see how the valleys are not symmetrical.

**Questions** After looking at some images of basketballs I still don't understand the remarks about the symmetry. But I really don't understand the instructions about how to make this model a real basketball, especially the parts about splitting the mesh and removing the doubles. Anyone ??

here is my file

[image]

I have tried the solution of Carlo and this is the Front Ortho view

[image]

This is the Back Ortho view

[image]

and this is the right side

[image]

Comment: check this page, it may give you some hint... http://www.badensports.eu/list.php?cat_id=2122

Comment: can you see there about the (a)symmetry ?

Comment: yes, I read "SYMMETRICAL DESIGN Perfection's symmetrical design gives you a perfectly balanced ball. Unlike any other basketball, the two halves of the ball are identical." and the image at right shows that...

Comment: You did almost right I think, but you probably didn't split the faces by pressing Y before rotating. Splitting will make you able to rotate one half indipendently from the other.

Comment: That's correct, but you have to perform the operation on both objects.

Comment: @Carlo Now I have gone through most of the tutorials (part 1, part 2) and there is one thing I don't get and that is how to UV unwrap the black rubber. This is shown in part 2 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-vQJ212l1c at about 35:00 min but I think that the changes you instructed me make it different. How to UV unwrap the Black Rubber ?

Comment: Can you join me in the chat? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31404/discussion-between-carlo-and-jan-scherders

Comment: @Carlo hi, I posted my result in the chat

Answer (score 8, accepted):

He is stating that he was inaccurate by mirroring the octave of the sphere in all three axis as on the Y is not symmetrical. This kind of ball, as in tennis and baseball is traditionally made by joining two complementary pieces

[image]

This is what you have at the moment:

[image]

Notice that the model is symmetrical on all the three axis while in the real traditional basketball (usually) isn't.

What you should see from one side is different from what you have on the other. Here's a pic of the different flows of the leather patches in the front and rear view:

[image]

As you can see each patch embrace the other, so one of them must be rotated by 90° from the other to join correctly.

[image]

The difference is only in which patch stop at their intersection. One time should be one and vice-versa.

---

**About the tutorial:**

What you probably missed is that the **Mirror modifier** should be **applied** before following the textual instructions, or you'll not able to edit the geometry.

[image]

*At the end of the gif it looks as if nothing wasn't changed at all but is just an illusion caused by overlapping geometry: I showed how to perform the instruction only on one of them.*

Comment: Nice shape keys based explanation .gif Carlo :). +1 from me.

Comment: I've added a couple of images to better explain the non-symmetry. Y axis in the Mirror modifier: the part that disappear if you uncheck the its box is the one that should be rotated.

Comment: i think I am a bit closer ... here is my file https://www.dropbox.com/s/tvihk4hyb31vl2u/basketball-2.blend?dl=0 I did the selection, the split and the rotation but i don't understand the last part of your coaching (the merge at distance). I still have something wrong in my mesh

Comment: Good, as before you splitted the faces (aka separated) to perform rotation, now you should merge the two halves by running the Remove Doubles command for vertex. The Merge Distance depend on the mesh density, I found that for the object named "Round cube" should be used a value of 0.01

Comment: While for the "Black rubber" a thereshold of 0.005 is more appropriate because is more detailed. This means that all the vertex inside the threshold will be merged, that's why you should not set it too high or part of the mesh will collapse.

Comment: could you maybe explain the Merge Distance (and where to find it) and how to apply it different for Round Cube and Black Rubber ?

Comment: You can find it in the operator panel, in the bottom left corner of the 3D view. I'll link a YT tutorial about the argument because I think it coud explain it better than me https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ADBmqYzxcwo but if you still have doubts after that, feel free to ask again and I'll write down something.

Comment: ok. should I first execute the select/split/rotate/remove doubles for the Round Cube and then for the Black Rubber ?

Comment: Which object you pick before is not a problem as they will remain separated, so you can start from any of them. When you run the Remove Doubles command yous set a different Merge Distance.

Comment: OK, I managed to execute the operation :) What effect does this have on the UV unwrapping ? I have now already executed the mirror modifier !?

Comment: No effect, as you should unwrap only at the end of modeling. To apply mirror modifiers before unwrapping is a good practice, expecially if you are not using seamsless textures.

Comment: hi, I think I now executed the operations as instructed both for the Round Cube and the Black Rubber but still something not OK as you can see in the images above. Did I do something wrong or do I have to repair something after such an operation ? here is my file https://www.dropbox.com/s/vqexj7pubh7rn5w/basketball-3.blend?dl=0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31404/discussion-between-carlo-and-jan-scherders).